# How to show another frame after the event?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

how to show another frame after button click event?
 [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSsrq.jpg)

My code here show window OnInit. but what to do next?
I did not find how to do this. little experience with this.
I comment the window that should be.

```
enum
{
    wxID_First_Load = 5000,
    wxID_First_Frame,
    wxID_First_Panel
};

class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size);
    void fileLoad(wxCommandEvent& event);
private:
    int file_count = 0;
    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};

wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
    EVT_BUTTON(wxID_First_Load, MyFrame::fileLoad)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);

bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame("Hello World", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(450, 250));
    frame->SetWindowStyle(wxCAPTION | wxSYSTEM_MENU );
    frame->Show(true);
    return true;
}

MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size)
    : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_First_Frame, title, pos, size)
{
        wxBoxSizer *first_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
        wxPanel *firstPanel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_First_Panel);
        wxButton *firstButton_Load = new wxButton(firstPanel, wxID_First_Load, "Choose file");

        firstPanel->SetSizer(first_sizer); 
        first_sizer->Add(firstButton_Load, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 10);
        firstPanel->SetSizer(first_sizer);
}

void MyFrame::fileLoad(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
    file_count = 2;
}
```

Second Frame or window:

```
wxPanel *firstPanel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_First_Panel);
wxBoxSizer *second_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
for (int i = 0; i < file_count; i++)
{
second_sizer->Add(new wxTextCtrl(firstPanel, wxWindowID(i), "Hello", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(235, 60)), wxSizerFlags(0).Border(wxALL, 5));
}
firstPanel->SetSizer(second_sizer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new frame you need to create a new object of `wxFrame` class or a class deriving from it. Typically, you want to put some data and logic into your new frame, so you would create some class, e.g. `MySecondaryFrame` (but hopefully with a better name) , inheriting from `wxFrame` in a similar way to your existing `MyFrame` class.

Then to show it you would do the same thing that you do in `MyApp::OnInit()`, i.e. create a new object of this class and call `Show()` to actually show it.

P.S. Note that your `SetWindowStyle(wxCAPTION | wxSYSTEM_MENU )` call is unnecessary, these styles are already on by default. Also, hard coding the frame size in pixels is a bad idea, consider using sizers to determine the best size suitable for the frame contents or just leave it unspecified if it really doesn't matter.